# RexExp test gives error on special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, regex-group

I am using RegExp to search text like below

```
 RegExp(searchText, "gi").test(field)
```

It works fine with words.

But when i user special character like + OR * it gives me error like below

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*/: Nothing to repeat
```

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here?

I don't have much knowledge of RegExp

I don't want to escape these special characters. They should match/search with my field.

Duplicate question gives method to replace special characters. I want to allow special characters to match/search.

Comment: _I don't want to escape these special characters._ You have to, otherwise you can't use regular expressions.

Comment: "I want to allow special characters to match/search." This is exactly what those duplicates do. Did you try them?